# Is HTML5 developed and documented enough?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, rtmp

I own a site which offers a Flash based music shopping cart which steams music using RTMP. Mobile devices are getting more and more popular and the exclusion of Flash means they don't support my Flash application. I was wondering if it's possible to create the same kind of Flash widget I have on my site in HTML5 or maybe even JavaScript alone? Is HTML5 developed enough for this kind of system? If possible, would users be able to embed an HTML5 version of our players? Can you stream music via RTMP using anything but Flash?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Change "Mobile devices" for iDevices. My Android phone runs Flash perfectly :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question YES HTML5 is documented and developed enough but the question that you should be asking is **"Is HTML5 supported enough?"**

HTML5 is markup AND JavaScript and its not supported in every browser. This is mitigated though by many great JavaScript libraries that will gracefully degrade depending on what browser/device is viewing it.

If you just want to learn more and make a decision for yourself I would suggest reading [Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) to figure out what HTML5 is all about and what it offers.

Comment: See also [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/) for up-to-date information on browser support.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot stream music using RTMP in HTML5. However, you can offer music in mp3 and ogg formats. (You'll need to offer both to cover all browsers)

After looking at your site, I would recommend you continue to use flash because HTML5 does not support streaming audio, only audio available to download. While the shopping cart and everything else can mostly be done in HTML5, your users will still need Flash unless you want to allow users to download the music easily.